# #SEQ keyword in Asp.Net Charting control with multiple Azure Cloud app instances

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, charts

I am having a simple Azure cloud app(WebRole=ASP.Net MVC) which draws charts using ASP.Net Charting control.

Specifications-->

1. Chart **RenderType** = ImageMap
2. Chart **ImageLocation** = **"/Images/Chart_#SEQ(1000,1)"**
3. Number of app instances deployed on Windows Azure = **5**
4. App contains a button which draws charts as per users parameters. When user clicks on this button, *MVC action* is called which provides necessary *ViewData* for drawing chart and returns a *partial view* which after getting rendered sends *ImageMap* and Image location to client.

[image]

When I try to draw charts from IE8 I always get the charts as per my parameters but when I simulataneously try to draw charts on FireFox sometimes I get wrong charts(wrong images).

Is it due to roundrobin used - #SEQ(1000,1) or due to mutiple instances of my cloud app ?

Comment: Nice diagram! Have you tried using Fiddler with Firefox for debugging?

Comment: Thanks. I have not used Fiddler with FireFox. I have used FireBug. Please tell me how will Fiddler help me ?

Comment: Not sure how familiar you are with Fiddler but it will allow you to have further clarity with in/out http traffic in order troubleshoot the IE/FF anomaly.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if FF vs IE is relevant here. Rather looks like a caching issue. On Windows Azure, the ASP.NET cache is NOT shared between worker instances. If your charting logic is depending on the cache, it might be causing the problem, as multiple requests might end up on distinct web role instances.

Comment: Yes I also think that main cause of this problem is multiple instances of cloud app. I guess this problem can be solved using AspSessionProvider for image storage.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a solution to this problem here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/fe6ccbdf-ec70-49f5-aef4-aada217938ed